# Cannot create and update records after updating Postgres.app and recreating db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a ruby on rails noobie and have upgraded postgress app to 9.4.2 (from 9.3.5) and ruby to 2.2.2 (from 2.2.1). After the update, I had to recreate and migrate the db from fresh.

I can't create and update any records anymore throughout the application (i.e. all controllers/views). It used to work before. The output I'm getting is:

```
Started GET "/expense_claims/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=iVEJfsXCoIKdngHRe6Zviqz6hqo8yT%2FAzpcEv73kYu47Q2Bdczqdm8RZZJyv%2BfJSVBexfglVczOXMQ1tXzJt%2BQ%3D%3D&expense_claim%5Bname%5D=Some+title+for+the+claim+comes+here&commit=Spesenabrechnung+erstellen" for ::1 at 2015-05-25 19:19:16 +0200
Processing by ExpenseClaimsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iVEJfsXCoIKdngHRe6Zviqz6hqo8yT/AzpcEv73kYu47Q2Bdczqdm8RZZJyv+fJSVBexfglVczOXMQ1tXzJt+Q==", "expense_claim"=>{"name"=>"Some title for the claim comes here"}, "commit"=>"Spesenabrechnung erstellen"}
  Rendered expense_claims/_form.html.slim (2.3ms)
  Rendered expense_claims/new.html.slim within layouts/application (4.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.html.slim (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flashes.html.slim (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_topbar.html.slim (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 947ms (Views: 945.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

It looks like it is a get-request instead of a post-request. The url after submitting is:
http://localhost:3000/expense_claims/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=iVEJfsXCoIKdngHRe6Zviqz6hqo8yT%2FAzpcEv73kYu47Q2Bdczqdm8RZZJyv%2BfJSVBexfglVczOXMQ1tXzJt%2BQ%3D%3D&expense_claim[name]=Some+title+for+the+claim+comes+here&commit=Spesenabrechnung+erstellen

For completeness, here an extract of one of the controllers:
Form:

```
= form_for(@expense_claim) do |f|

  - if @expense_claim.errors.any?
    ul.error-messages
      - @expense_claim.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        li.error-message = message

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Juni Spesenabrechnung', maxlength: 100, class: 'form-control'
    p.help-block
      | Ein beschreibender Titel für die Spesenabrechnung, damit Du Dich erinnern kannst, was sie enthält.

  .actions
    = f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to 'Abbrechen', expense_claims_path, class: 'btn btn-link'
```

Controller:

```
  def new
    @expense_claim = ExpenseClaim.new
  end

  def create
    @expense_claim = ExpenseClaim.new(expense_claim_params)

    if @expense_claim.save
      redirect_to @expense_claim, notice: 'Spesenabrechnung wurde erstellt'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Model:

```
class ExpenseClaim < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :receipts
  has_many :mileages

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

resources:

```
resources :expense_claims
```

I can create and update records through the terminal without any problems and for all controllers. After trying to solve this for hours, I'm at a loss why it suddenly doesn't work anymore. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the expense_claim is not saving and therefore the new template is being rendered. Try putting some logging in the controller to see what is happening in the create action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to verify that the `create` controller action is actually being called, since that's the only place that database changes are being made right? Right after `def create`, add a line like the following:

```
puts "#create called with params: #{params}"
```

and verify that this line appears in your Rails server console output.

I'm confused by the output you pasted (at top), because that's a GET request to the `new` action. Remember Rails resourceful routing defaults expect 2 steps to creating something:

1. `GET #new` shows the form for preparing the data on that resource
2. When the form is submitted, it POSTs to `#create` where the new animal is actually created.

It looks like either you're copying & pasting the wrong section of console output, or your form is never getting submitted.

Also, go to `GET #new` and inspect the HTML code for the form. In particular you should see `method="post"` and `action="/expense_claims [NOT expense_claims/new]"`.

Good luck!

Comment: form looks ok to me: <form class="new_expense_claim" id="new_expense_claim" action="/expense_claims" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">. However, it doesn't hit the create action, at least your suggested output is not shown.

Comment: Huh. Something's fishy, if the form defines the method as POST then your browser should definitely send a POST request when you click the submit button, and the Rails server console should register a POST request not a GET. Can you open up Chrome's developer tools (Network tab) and verify what kind of request is getting sent?

Comment: It's indeed a get request instead of a post request that is being sent. How is this possible?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Can you paste the entire form HTML in your question? The only thing I can think of is, perhaps when you click the Submit button a Javascript handler is triggering instead of the form actually getting submitted. Any chance of that?

Comment: Solved it thanks to Topher's tip. There was a get request because I didn't close the sidebar search form properly, so rails thought the submit belongs to the sidebar form instead of the new main form. Thanks for the help